# IOS App Version Support After uploading to library

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store

I have successfully uploaded IOS app onto app store and the current status is "Waiting For Review", so my question is after my app successfully comes on store, will it support for all OS versions of Iphone or do i need to make some specific changes in Xcode / apple account / my Code to make it happen.
plz help..

Note : target OS is 5.0..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will support the version set in the target or greater.
Select the root project file, and in the info tab - set the minimum deployment target to 4.3 (for example). You will have to fix any errors that arise (for instance lack of support for 'automated __weak references')

Once you again successfully compile the application, re-submitted it to the AppStore with that version

Comment: you dont need to download an older Xcode and sdk. this is plain wrong and not recommended either. that's what the deployment target is for - like described in the other answers

Comment: Not able to remove the answer since it is the accepted one, I at least have updated it with more accurate information.

Answer (score 2):

When you develop an app then you need to specify Minimum Deployment Target for your application. App will only run on those devices which has iOS equal or grater to this value. If you specify min deployment target to 5.0 then you app will only run on devices which has iOS 5.0 or later. Also it doesn't mean that your app will successfully run on all versions grater then iOS 5.0

Once you submit your app to app store then you can't change it. if you want to do this then you need to add another version. If your app is in "Waiting for review" then you have the option to use developer reject and re-upload it.

Comment: Thanks a lot but i want to know mostly people use which version iphone , 5 or lower than 5..

Comment: it depends on how you design your app. In recent day developers prefer iOS >= 6.0